Trying to read a .csv0000_000 file from aws into R
I have access to an AWS bucket with a bunch of files I want to read into Rstudio. Bur for some reason the files are all saved as .csv0000_000 types on AWS. When I was working with a few of the smaller files, I just downloaded them to my laptop and manually changed their names to .csv and they worked just fine when I uploaded them into R. However now that I am trying to read in hundreds of them straight from AWS I can;t download them to change their names (too big to store on my computer) and I don't know how to read them in as csvs into R studio so I can analyze them.
So far I have tried
bucket <- s3_bucket("path")
file <- "file.csv0000_000"
csv_data <- aws.s3::get_object(bucket = bucket, object = file, check_region = FALSE)


And got this error:
Error in UseMethod("get_bucketname") : 
  no applicable method for 'get_bucketname' applied to an object of class "c('SubTreeFileSystem', 'FileSystem', 'ArrowObject', 'R6')"

Any help would be appreciated!
